# Restrict users from entering unwanted texts in datetime field

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, datetime

I have a datetime field ( thru date picker) in Visual force page , while on submitting the form , i receive the entered date in the Apex class for validation purpose. How to check whether the user has entered a date or some other text , How can i check this .

`<apex:inputText id="moveindate" value="{!moveindate}" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, true);" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a input text try the code below, adjust your pattern matcher according to your desired format. Datepicker by default gives mm/dd/yyy hh:mm AM/PM.

This article will give your more insight on pattern matcher : http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2010/01/utilizing-apex-pattern-and-matcher.html

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="pattern_match">
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:form >
<apex:inputText id="moveindate" value="{!moveindate}" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, true);" />
<apex:commandButton value="check number" action="{!checkfornumber}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class pattern_match {
    public string moveindate{get;set;}
    public String date_format{get;set;}
    public Pattern MyPattern  {get;set;}
    public pattern_match (){
        moveindate = '';
    }

    public pagereference checkfornumber(){
    MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d) ([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]) (AM|PM)');
    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(moveindate);
        if(!MyMatcher.matches()){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: valid string is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `apex:inputField` that is bound to a date-time field, you do not need to validate anything. The system will automatically validate the input for you based on the user's locale. Otherwise, if it is a normal text field, you should use `DateTime.parse` inside a `try-catch` block. If the date is invalid, you'll get an exception, if not, it is a valid date-time. The best part is, it automatically tries to validate the input based on the user's locale, so some users might use 'mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy', or some other format (of course, you're using the date picker, so that should help), and the system will usually understand their intent.

Comment: sorry im using `inputText`

Comment: You can verify the input from inputText using the DateTime.parse function, then, as outlined in the answer.